# Teleoperationg a Turtlebot without a wireless joystick

Tags: ros, turtlebot, joystick, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone knows a way to teleoperate a turtlebot through a joystick plugged on the workstation? I don't have a wireless joystick...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11234/teleoperationg-a-turtlebot-without-a-wireless-joystick/) by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2011-09-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you take a look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) and set up the roscore to run on the workstation and point the TurtleBot's ROS_MASTER_URI to the workstation, you can run the joy node and your teleop node on the workstation and the TurtleBot will receive those commands. Be careful, however, because I've seen significant lag while teleoping over the network, but it will work.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jie Sky](https://answers.ros.org/users/20509/jie-sky/) on 2014-11-25**:
Do you know how to use a normal joystick to control a turtlebot based kobuki?I have some trouble with it . I refer to this website:http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_teleop/Tutorials/hydro/Joystick%20Teleop